# How should I check if two nodes have relationship with each other,in neo4j embedded database in java?

Tags: neo4j, embedded-database, java

How should I check if two nodes have relationship with each other,in neo4j embedded database in java?

I want the syntax please or a tutorial link,I have seen neo4j website but didn't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given two nodes "nodeA" and "nodeB",

1. gets all relationships attached to "nodeA",

   ```
   rels = nodeA.getRelationships();
   ```
2. iterate through the collection of relationships "rels", for each relationship "rel", test whether the other end node is nodeB

   ```
   rel.getOtherNode(nodeA).equals(nodeB)
   ```
3. if the above expression holds true for one of the relationships, then nodeA and nodeB are connected.

Here is the java API for "Node" and "Relationshiip",

http://api.neo4j.org/current/

Comment: I just thought I would add, that you should consider the edge counts of `nodeA` and `nodeB` before performing this search, as you can perform it starting from either node.

Comment: This does not work well if you potentially have many thousands of relationships.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean sharedRelationshipExists( Node nodeA, long nodeBId)
{
    Iterator<Relationship> iterator = nodeA.getRelationships().iterator();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() )
    {
        if (iterator.next().getOtherNode( nodeA ).getId() == nodeBId) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// in another part
boolean sharedRelationshipBetweenAB;
if ( nodeA.getDegree() < nodeB.getDegree() )
{
    sharedRelationshipBetweenAB = sharedRelationshipExists( nodeA, nodeB.getId() );
}
else
{
    sharedRelationshipBetweenAB = sharedRelationshipExists( nodeB, nodeA.getId() );
}
```

the boolean `sharedRelationshipBetweenAB` will hold your answer